# EntityFramework Add-Migration crashes vwdexpress.exe via System.Data.SqlServerCe

Tags: entity-framework, migration, sql-server-ce, visual-web-developer-2010

Visual Web Developer Express is crashing when I run the EntityFramework 'add-migration' command from the package manager console.

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name: CLR20r3  
  Problem Signature 01: vwdexpress.exe  
  Problem Signature 02: 10.0.40219.1  
  Problem Signature 03: 4d5f2a69  
  Problem Signature 04: System.Data.SqlServerCe  
  Problem Signature 05: 4.0.8876.1  
  Problem Signature 06: 4fcd17f1  
  Problem Signature 07: 401  
  Problem Signature 08: 17  
  Problem Signature 09: System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCe  
  OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48  
  Locale ID: 1033  

Additional information about the problem:  
  LCID: 1033
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a response on msdn. Reinstalled SQL Server Compact Edition and the migration was successfully scaffolded.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30709